# How to make furrows darker?

Tags: materials, shaders, shadows

Another day of the 3D artist. How to make furrows darker?
is it possible to make an analogue of "ambient occlusion" using only the Shader Editor? The gradient texture doesn't work as I expect.
[image]

[image]
(Blender 3.2.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in Eevee, in Eevee there are at least 2 solutions: the ***AO*** node and the ***Dirty Vertex Colors***.

Use an *Input > AO* node as factor in your *Shader Editor*, you just need to activate the option in the *Render* panel:

[image]

For the *Dirty Vertex Colors* solution: Switch to *Solid* viewport shading mode and switch to *Vertex Paint* mode, then go into the header menu > *Paint > Dirty Vertex Colors*:

[image]

Tweak the factors in the *Operator* box until you get what you want:

[image]

The operation has created a *Vertex Colors* in the *Object Data* panel. Switch to *Rendered* preview or *Material* preview, in your *Shader Editor* create an *Input > Vertex Colors* node, use it as factor:

[image]

In Cycles there's also the *Geometry* node and its *Pointiness* output, you could bake the result if you want to use it in Eevee.

Comment: is there a way to achieve this result without using the "Ambient Occlusion" option? Using only the Shader Editor.

Comment: You could bake a AO map or a Pointiness map in Cycles and use it in Eevee

Comment: In Eevee itself you could use the Dirty Vertex Colors in Vertex Paint but it needs more geometry that what you have currently, so you'll need to subdivide, but here again you could bake a map to come back to a low-poly version

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look carefully at the image, that's exactly what I was asking. Thank you.

Comment: Oh actually it could work fine with Dirty Vertex Colors too, I'll edit my answer

Comment: This is also a great option, special thanks for it.